# React does not export its components via ES6 so IntelliJ throws warnings

Tags: intellij-idea, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webstorm

I am writing a `React` app using `ES6` like so

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

I have installed react via `npm`, business as usual

```
npm install react --save-dev
```

It seems though that `React` is written using *CommonJs* as

```
module.exports = React;
```

so IntelliJ (or WebStorm) will throw a warning

> default export is not declared in imported module

which is kind of bugging me and also autocompletion won't work. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with `import { pg } from 'pg';`--no react involved. `import pg from 'pg';` doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Webstorm 2016.2. I don't know how to fix the warning but I was able to disable it. Use Alt-Enter and accept the fix. Here is the fix, notice the comment, that is the fix.

```
//noinspection TypeScriptCheckImport
import template from './app.html';
```

Answer (score 1):

Though [WEB-19542](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19542) is not yet fixed, I can't see this error reported for React in WebStorm 12 RC; Ctrl+click on it opens node_modules\react\react.js

Comment: [WEB-19699](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19699) is a linked issue that more simply describes the root of the problem.